# How to move down half of the row in label control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im using label control.
The row that contained in label control is too long and i want 
half of the line to move down.

for example label looks like that:

> Follow American politics, keep up with the hottest political debates.

I want it to be like this:

> Follow American politics, keep up with the
>
> hottest political debates, and share your.

Any idea how to implemet this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your text going to be fixed ? and also where `and share your` text came from ? it was not there in the original text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is **text wrapping**, try the below:

First, set the label's property [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize) to `True`.

Then, the next key property is [`MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.maximumsize.aspx). You should set its width (or height) to a fixed value, not the default 0. If the text goes over that width, the label will auto-wrap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it :

```
label2.Text = "Follow American politics, keep up with the"+System.Environment.NewLine+ "hottest political debates, and share your";
```

Comment: Will work if the text is fixed. (The OP did not say whether it is.) Optionally, using `\n` can be a shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following technique. 
Get length of the string, divide it by `2` to get half length, from there look for the space and add `Environment.NewLine`. Something on the following lines:

```
string Text = "Follow American politics, keep up with the hottest political debates.";
int halfLength = Text.Length / 2;
int cuttOffPoint = Text.IndexOf(' ', halfLength);
Text = Text.Substring(0, cuttOffPoint) + Environment.NewLine+Text.Substring(cuttOffPoint);
yourLabel.Text = Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than above mentioned methods you can use set `AutoSize = false` property of the label control